# Reorder table rows in an arbitrary order based on row ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I want to use jQuery to reorder some table rows based on an **arbitrary** order I choose when a user clicks a link or button.
(Note: I'm not after a table row sort based on the alpha/numeric contents of the cells or column headings - I know there are js plugins like 'Animated Table Sorter' for that)

**heres my code sample:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a id="custom-sort-1" href="#">Custom Sort 1</a></li>
    <li><a id="custom-sort-2" href="#">Custom Sort 2</a></li>
</ul>

<table>
    <tr id="row-a">
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row-b">
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row-c">
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row-d">
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**What I want to happen:**

- Clicking "#custom-sort-1" would re-order the table rows: row-c,
  row-a, row-d, row-b
- Clicking "#custom-sort-2" would re-order the
  table rows: row-a, row-c, row-b, row-d

How would I use Jquery to do that?

As an added feature - how would you animate the changing row order?

Comment: you could use css (:checked, flex and order): for the fun : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/EWjqKQ but no animation moving them around

Comment: ha! thats very clever - and nice to not necessarily rely on js.

Answer (score 0):

One can use jQuery to get the elements as a list, enumerate over them, build a javascript array from the IDs, use the javascript built in .sort() method of the array object by providing custom compare function that will have to include the logic for the arbitrary sort(one would need to keep a variable with the button clicked value), and then use jQuery to rearrange the elements using jQuery methods for DOM manipulation, like: .add(), .insert(), .append(), .after() and include animation in them.

Comment: thanks - that certainly sounds right in theory. I guess its the actual syntax i'm looking to see an example of as i'm a newbie on the JS front - hence the question :)